# Configuration parameters accessed from Entity in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Is there a way to access sessions or configuration parameters from inside the Entity?
I would like to have access to app.session.xyz in every Entity in all of my bundles.
Is it possible to configure doctrine or create some service to archive this?

Comment: At best you can do is creating event listener service and inject the services you want to access. See [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) cookbook entry.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea. Your entities must not contains any logic.
All your business logic should live inside dedicated services.

Anyway, it's not possible.
You can't use the DIC to inject services into entities because it do not know how to create them.